# How to stop a mosquito from flying?

Tags: entomology

[Researchers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jfluidstructs.2015.03.016) have found mosquitoes cannot fly in dense fog because fog particles adhere to its halteres and stop them working. Is it possible to disrupt mosquitoes flight by mimicking fog particles?

Comment: Most of mosquitoes species don't fly if the wind speed is over a certain (normally low) limit. That's the logic of using fans to get (some) relief, and it's the most widespread form of artificially (just joking, I don't know what you mean by *artificially*) preventing mosquitoes from flying.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Remove its wings by pulling on them is one way to stop a mosquito to fly "artificially". Does it answer your question? If not, then you should probably clarify your question.

Comment: It would be good if you shared the link of the paper with this discovery.

Comment: @Tytoalba link has been added - it's pretty cool! :-) Anything that gives mosquitos a hard time around me is a good thing. I'm going out to buy some custom Krypton/Oxygen mix now.

Comment: @VictorChung this is a really interesting paper, thanks for bringing it to people's attention! Can you consider focusing your question on something specific that could be answered? Something that's not necessarily answered in the paper itself?